# Research for Info

Tags: stocks

One share of Essex Chemical Corp common stock issued Feb 15 1967 was found by a relative, given to me to research. A quick search, indicated this company was obtained by Dow Chemical. How do I find if stock has value?

Comment: http://www.dow-dupont.com/investors/default.aspx#contacts

Answer (score 2):

quid's link should give you a definitive answer, but just to set expectations, here's [an article from the UPI](http://www.upi.com/Archives/1988/09/06/Essex-Chemical-agrees-to-acquisition-by-Dow-Chemical/5310589521600/):

> Essex Chemical Corp. has agreed to be acquired by Dow Chemical Co. in a $366 million, **$36-a-share** deal ... Any shares that remain outstanding after the merger will be converted into the right to **receive $36 each in cash**, the companies said.

There's no mention of exchange for Dow stock, so it's likely that you would get $36 for this share of stock, if anything.

Comment: $36 in 1988 dollars should be worth about $75 in 2017 dollars (inflation, etc).   But you may very well be stuck with just $36, unless there was a time limit on the offer.

Comment: There may have been potential stock splits in the time frame between 1967-1988.